# How to Track Data Difference in Data Pipeline

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, data-science

We have a set of user data that comes in every week. Its in Millions. It consists of bunch of attributes for user (visits, category, product etc) by timestamp.

Now every week, a few 100k records are changed- updated, deleted, added etc. This means same user which had certain record last week, might have got some values changed in some attribute etc. Or new users might have got added completely

however, we still currently run the pipeline that feeds off this data every week for downstream tasks, on the entire 11MM + users in its entirety.

That consumes computation resources and hence cloud cost.

Is there a way/tool that helps in only figuring out which user records got updated from previous run so we can only do downstream processing on those 100k records or so instead of running it for entire dataset every week?

Analogy in code versioning is git diff etc which helps to know incremental patches/changes to a file.

For a data eng ETL process, what could be the right tool/way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A couple of strategies that I know of.

1. Firstly, `last_updated_timestamp`. Simply find the records where `last_updated_timestamp` is greater than your last batch's `max(last_updated_timestamp)`. If you don't have `last_updated_timestamp`, I suggest start implementing it. This is probably the cheapest method.
2. Secondly, if there is really still a need to further filter down, you can use a hash of a concatenation of all the fields. Example, `MD5(field1 || field 2 || ...)`. This is only worthwhile if the first method is unreliable, because even if you have the hash, comparing them (essentially joining your existing records with the new batch) is not a cheap operation. Unreliable here means due to external factor, such as user behavior. If it is unreliable because it was not implemented properly, fixing it is still the way to go.

Comment: is there any ETL tool that can do this diff work?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the concern. Using the second strategy I mentioned, most ETL tools I know can do the comparison. Just do a left join on the PK, and use the hash to determine if it should insert, update, or do nothing. But as I mentioned, suggest the first option.

Comment: what are those ETL tools? we use AWS so I am looking if there is a way we can use some tool to do this data diff instead of having to code this

Comment: Talend, AWS Glue, Beam, or even stored procedures on database, but yeah need to code. The code for option 1 would be a one-liner though, and option 2 is a simple left join and hash. Is there a specific concern that it has to be no code?

Comment: just wondering if other ETL tools can do if faster than code hash and join. We have weekly tens of millions of records and even if incremental is 100k+ every week, they would be matched with prior week entire data (tens of millions) on hash and concern is if that is inefficient

Comment: I see. Just to clarify, the join / match will not be on hash, but on the PK. The DB should be optimized to find records on PK (typically already the case for OLTP, or using index or distribution key for OLAP). Hence, the hash comparison will only be 100k+ against 100k+, not tens of millions. To be honest, for typical data warehouse, 100k writes should be a breeze, so might as well skip the hash comparison. If it is slow, it is likely an issue in the DB not optimized for the join step.

Comment: I believe the join on 100k vs 100k is applicable for the first option. But not for the second option with hash right? Because in second u r suggesting, create a hash of each record in table (so essentially 10MM+ records) and then going forward match the incremental records (100K+) hash with all prior one time created hash of all 10MM+. So every week we have then 100k vs 10MM+ hash comparison?

Comment: No, in terms of order of execution, (1) you should first left join 100k vs 10M based on the PK. This should be fast because the DB can be optimized to do so. This results in 100k records. Then, (2) compute the hash and compare only for this set.

Comment: And again note that this is only worthwhile if out of 100k records, a significant portion is really unchanged. Say, 50k or more is unchanged. Otherwise, if most of the 100k is a valid update, the hash comparison is an extra effort with no added value. Better spend the effort on updating the 100k records, or if it is slow, investigating why the update is slow (e.g., is delete/insert faster? do we need to upscale?).